# Creating a VIEW that RESTRICTS user access to certain hours

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to perform the following query **"Create a view which restricts staff user access to the order table  to the working hours between 9:00 and 18:00. Grant appropriate 
permissions to the staff users."**

However I am struggling, what I have used so far is the following:

```
   CREATE VIEW STAFF_RESTRICTORDERVIEW AS
   SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), ORDERNUMBER, CUSTOMERNUMBER, DATEORDERPLACED, DELIVERYINSTRUCTION, SCHEDULEID, 
   FROM ORDERS
   WHERE STAFF_RESTRICTORDERVIEW (SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') NOT BETWEEN
   (SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY 09:00:00') AND (SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY 18:00:00')
```

If that code above worked, then I would have been able to add the following:

```
  GRANT SELECT on STAFF_RESTRICTORDERVIEW TO 'STAFF_USER'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :).

Comment: Well it looks like you're missing a `'`, for one.

Comment: Could use some clarification.  This sort of sounds like a college/grad school database assignment.  Questions: how are the staff users connecting to the DB, under personal accounts or a shared user account?  Is the order table owned by some shared user account?  What are 'appropriate permissions'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW STAFF_RESTRICTORDERVIEW (
    current_sys_date, 
    ordernumber, 
    customernumber, 
    dateorderplaced,
    deliveryinstruction, 
    scheduleid
) AS
SELECT 
    sysdate, 
    ORDERNUMBER, 
    CUSTOMERNUMBER, 
    DATEORDERPLACED, 
    DELIVERYINSTRUCTION, 
    SCHEDULEID
 FROM ORDERS
 WHERE SYSDATE NOT BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) + 9/24 and trunc(sysdate) + 18/24
```

I believe that this would return an empty recordset if you run it between 9:00 and 18:00.  If you want the reverse, to only get records between those hours, then remove the NOT from the final line.

Comment: A- I don't believe you want the `NOT`.  You want the query to return 0 rows if the time is before 9am or after 6pm.

Comment: Than you, the above code worked. Thank you all for your kind help, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please accept my answer if it solved your problem, that's the best way to thank folks on SO. :)

Comment: There should be a hollow check below the voting buttons you can click, see this for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work